# How to merge files to single executable or decrease the number of distributed files

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ilmerge

I have such output files of my WPF application:

```
de\
es\
fr\
hu\
it\
pt-BR\
Resources\
ro\
ru\
sv\
zh-Hans\
FileHelpers.dll
FileHelpers.DataLink.dll
FileHelpers.ExcelStorage.dll
Interop.Excel.dll
Interop.Office.dll
Ionic.Zip.dll
wpftoolkit.dll
Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.dll
Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Themes.Aero.dll
Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Themes.Metro.dll
Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Themes.VS2010.dll
Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.dll
Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.dll
MyApp.Common.Extensions.dll
MyApp.Common.Helpers.dll
MyApp.Common.Types.Attributes.dll
MyApp.Security.dll
MyApp.Wpf.Controls.dll
MyApp.exe
MyApp.exe.config
licence.key
error.log
```

Everything started from `MyApp` is developed by myself, everything else done by 3dParty
I want to distribute my app but in order to do that I want to merge everything what is possible to distribute the minimum ammmount of files.

I was trying to use ilmerge to merge my files in to single one but was getting an error:

`ILMerge.Merge: ERROR!!: Duplicate type 'XamlGeneratedNamespace.GeneratedInternal
TypeHelper' found in assembly 'Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid'.`
The answer on that question I found here [xeed error reason](http://xceed.com/CS/forums/thread/33259.aspx)
Than I've being reading [ilmerge limitations](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) and [assembly as resources by Jeffrey Richter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx)

So I found Jeffrey Richter solution is quite useful. But I cant apply that for my program because there is no 'Build Action' attribute on assemblies.

Is there anything I can do in order to achieve my goal?

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to minimize the number of files? It just doesn't seem like a very productive use of your time..

Comment: @Miky Dinescu he he, you might be right, but I want to understand why Jeffry idea is not working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at RedGate's SmartAssembly.

Comment: Heh, I will try i t out, but I still wondering why Jeffry's approach is not working in my case..

Answer (score 7):

To make Jeffrey's idea working you should add your assemblies not only as references. Just add dlls as existing item (right click on project->Add->Existing Item) to your project and you will get **Build Action** property on them. Also set **Copy local** property to **false** on the references that you add as an embedded resource.

[image]

**App** class constructor:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
    }
    static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        var dllName = new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll";
        var execAsm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var resourceName = execAsm.GetManifestResourceNames().FirstOrDefault(s => s.EndsWith(dllName));
        if (resourceName == null) return null;
        using (var stream = execAsm.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
        {
            var assbebmlyBytes = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(assbebmlyBytes, 0, assbebmlyBytes.Length);
            return Assembly.Load(assbebmlyBytes);
        }

    }
}
```

Pay attention that this method consume more memory than usual dll loading.

Comment: Great and also will be using `RedGate's SmartAssembly` as @gap suggested

Comment: How does this affect the referenced assemblies list under the references folder? Does this affect compile time or run time? I am really keen on checking this out got no idea how this all works?

Comment: You must have references on all assemblies like in normal situation to provide all necessary info about types to the compiler. You set Copy local to false because all assemblies (which are not in GAC) you load from resources during runtime. This happens when CLR meets types from this Dlls first time and call JIT compilation. Because of this you can't use such types directly in Main().