# Problems with dynamically loading MVVM Light assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I planned to write a WPF application using MVVM Light and wanted to distribute it with just the executable only, meaning only the "MyApp.exe" (without all the other MVVM Light assemblies).

The idea I had was to embed all the assemblies in the project resources and then dynamically load it when the app starts up, such as calling the following block of code within App.xaml.cs.

```
private static void LoadAllAssemblies()
{
  var assemblies = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames().Where(x => x.EndsWith(".dll")).ToList();

  foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
  {
      using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(assembly))
      {
          if (stream == null)
              continue;

          var data = new Byte[stream.Length];
          stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

          Assembly.Load(data);
      }
  }
}
```

The problem now is that whenever I try to run it, it keeps on giving me a exception with the following message, "

> The invocation of the constructor on type
>   'MyApp.Framework.ViewModelLocator' that matches the specified binding
>   constraints threw an exception.

Any idea why this is happening and how this could be done? Or is it even doable?

Comment: May be this answer will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735459/how-to-merge-files-to-single-executable-or-decrease-the-number-of-distributed-fi/19735975#19735975

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint in this method?

Comment: @Deffiss thanks.. it works perfectly now. But I don't get it, what's the difference here between me manually loading all the assemblies versus loading it through the event handler?

Comment: @Bizz yes, this method is being called and run perfectly fine

Comment: @ShiewCheongTang The difference in lazy loading. By the way where do you call your LoadAllAssemblies() method? I just have made some experiments (not with MVVM Ligth) and all works perfectly when I call LoadAllAssemblies() method in the constructor of the App class.

Comment: @Deffiss I called it within my App constructor as well. It works fine with other projects, it just this particular case where I'm having some binding issues. Anyway, the lazy loading method now works even better than my original implementation.

Comment: @ShiewCheongTang Glad to help. It will be great if you upvote for my answer about lazy loading :)